# Define column type for enum

Tags: hibernate

Upon upgrading from 6.1.7 to 6.2.0, I get this error message during schema validation:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [receiving_status] in table [buddies_anonymized]; found [int (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [tinyint (Types#TINYINT)]
```

The full class `BuddyAnonymized` can be found [here](https://github.com/yonadev/yona-server/blob/master/core/src/main/java/nu/yona/server/subscriptions/entities/BuddyAnonymized.java). The attribute `receivingStatus` is declared as follows (no annotations applied):

```
private Status receivingStatus = Status.NOT_REQUESTED;
```

The type Status is an enum, defined as follows:

```
public enum Status
{
    NOT_REQUESTED, REQUESTED, ACCEPTED, REJECTED
}
```

This issue I reported on the Hibernate project as [HHH-16422](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16422). As I didn't get a response yet, I wanted to implement a workaround and explicitly define the column type, like this:

```
    @Column(columnDefinition = "INTEGER")
    private Status receivingStatus = Status.NOT_REQUESTED;
```

However, the same error is still being reported. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I got a response from the Hibernate team: This is a documented breaking change in Hibernate 6.2, see [the 6.2 migration guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.2/migration-guide.adoc#datatype-for-enums).

The solution is to add the `@JdbcType` annotation, as follows:

```
@JdbcType(value = SmallIntJdbcType.class)
private Status receivingStatus = Status.NOT_REQUESTED;
```

Answer (score -1):

use columnDefinition = "int":

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "int")
private Status receivingStatus = Status.NOT_REQUESTED;
```

this worked for me

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not fix it for me